# Enable IntelliSense on XAML Content resources in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, resharper, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with ReSharper 10 to edit XAML files.

IntelliSense in enabled in the XAML editor if the Build Action of the XAML file is set to `Page`, i.e. it gets compiled into the assembly as a BAML2006 resource. I would like to edit XAML file with the `Content` Build Action instead, because I would like to use XAML 2009 language features and copy the XAMl file into the output directory. Unfortunately, setting `Copy If Newer` with the `Page` build action does not result in the XAML file getting copied into the output.

If I set the Build Action to `Content`, I lose IntelliSense editor support. There still appears to be some kind of syntax and semantic checking, since I get warnings for misspelled tag and attribute names and XAML 2009 features. *Is there any way to restore full IntelliSense support?*

Xamarin Forms appears to have released an extension related to XAML IntelliSense support: http://www.cazzulino.com/enable-xaml-forms-intellisense.html However, it only seems to enable the XAML editor for Forms resources instead of the XML editor. As I can open files in the XAML editor already, I don't think a similar approach could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS2015 and Resharper10 to and IntelliSense on XAML is working. In my case the BuildAction is AndroidResource.

To make it work tried this document but in the path mentioned there did not have the schemas
https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1920119-how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-android-axml-files-

Where I found the schemas is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin
>   Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\schemas

Then opened an .axml file in Source mode and in VS main menu:
    XML -> Schemas -> Add dialog.

Comment: AFAIK this only enables XML IntelliSense for .xaml files, i.e. autocomplete data will come from an .xsd style, not from the actual reflective XamlSchemaContext. If you add an XML prolog to the .xaml file, is it highlighted in gray (XAML editor, XamlSchemaContext reflection), or is the version="1.0" part highlighted appropriately as an attribute and a string (XML editor, .xsd schema)?